# Update n random rows in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have table which is having about 1000 rows.I have to update a column("X") in the table to 'Y' for n ramdom rows. For this i can have following query

```
update xyz set X='Y' when m in (
'SELECT m FROM (SELECT m
FROM xyz
order by dbms_random.value
) RNDM 
where rownum < n+1);
```

Is there another efficient way to write this query. The table has no index.
Please help?

Comment: If you don't actually care which rows are updated, what's wrong with it just updating the top `rownum` rows?  If there is no explicit order to the command, you get a non-guarunteed ordering (granted, it's _probably_ file-insert, but not necessarily) in any case.  Updating "a random row" usually means "I don't care which one" - unless you need it distributed throughout the table, at which point you could just select every fifth one or something (possibly by the `id` column).

Comment: @X-Zero: Could be that the update is part of a process for sampling records for further review, testing, QA, etc. In which case random versus non-determined is an important distinction. That's what I assumed OP is looking for when he asked for random.

Comment: @Shannon - Or for giving random contest rewards; you could be right.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use the ROWID:

```
UPDATE xyz SET x='Y' WHERE rowid IN (
    SELECT r FROM (
        SELECT ROWID r FROM xyz ORDER BY dbms_random.value
    ) RNDM WHERE rownum < n+1
)
```

The actual reason I would use ROWID isn't for efficiency though (it will still do a full table scan) - your SQL may not update the number of rows you want if column `m` isn't unique.

With only 1000 rows, you shouldn't really be worried about efficiency (maybe with a hundred million rows).  Without any index on this table, you're stuck doing a full table scan to select random records.

**[EDIT:]**  *"But what if there are 100,000 rows"*

Well, that's still 3 orders of magnitude less than 100 million.

I ran the following:

```
create table xyz as select * from all_objects;
```

[created about 50,000 rows on my system - non-indexed, just like your table]

```
UPDATE xyz SET owner='Y' WHERE rowid IN (
     SELECT r FROM (
          SELECT ROWID r FROM xyz ORDER BY dbms_random.value
     ) RNDM WHERE rownum < 10000
);
commit;
```

This took approximately 1.5 seconds.  Maybe it was 1 second, maybe up to 3 seconds (didn't formally time it, it just took about enough time to blink).

Answer (score 6):

You can improve performance by replacing the full table scan with a sample.

The first problem you run into is that you can't use SAMPLE in a DML subquery, `ORA-30560: SAMPLE clause not allowed`.  But logically this is what is needed:

```
UPDATE xyz SET x='Y' WHERE rowid IN (
    SELECT r FROM (
        SELECT ROWID r FROM xyz sample(0.15) ORDER BY dbms_random.value
    ) RNDM WHERE rownum < 100/*n*/+1
);
```

You can get around this by using a collection to store the rowids, and then update the rows using the rowid collection.  Normally breaking a query into separate parts and gluing them together with PL/SQL leads to horrible performance.  But in this case you can still save a lot of time by significantly reducing the amount of data read.

```
declare
    type rowid_nt is table of rowid;
    rowids rowid_nt;
begin
    --Get the rowids
    SELECT r bulk collect into rowids
    FROM (
        SELECT ROWID r
        FROM xyz sample(0.15)
        ORDER BY dbms_random.value
    ) RNDM WHERE rownum < 100/*n*/+1;

    --update the table
    forall i in 1 .. rowids.count
        update xyz set x = 'Y'
        where rowid = rowids(i);
end;
/
```

I ran a simple test with 100,000 rows (on a table with only two columns), and N = 100.
The original version took 0.85 seconds, @Gerrat's answer took 0.7 seconds, and the PL/SQL version took 0.015 seconds.

But that's only one scenario, I don't have enough information to say my answer will always be better. As N increases the sampling advantage is lost, and the writing will be more significant than the reading. If you have a very small amount of data, the PL/SQL context switching overhead in my answer may make it slower than @Gerrat's solution.

For performance issues, the size of the table in bytes is usually much more important than the size in rows.  1000 rows that use a terabyte of space is much larger than 100 million rows that only use a gigabyte.

Here are some problems to consider with my answer:

1. Sampling does not always return exactly the percent you asked for.  With 100,000 rows and a 0.15% sample size the number of rows returned was 147, not 150.  That's why I used 0.15 instead of 0.10.  You need to over-sample a little bit to ensure that you get more than N.  How much do you need to over-sample?  I have no idea, you'll probably have to test it and pick a safe number.
2. You need to know the approximate number of rows to pick the percent.
3. The percent must be a literal, so as the number of rows and `N` change, you'll need to use dynamic SQL to change the percent.

Comment: @jonearless:  +1  Nice, informative answer.  I considered mentioning the sampling, but it's just unneeded complexity/overkill in 99% of the cases.  It's good to mention though for those with an overwhelming need for premature optimization. :)

Answer (score 2):

The following solution works just fine. It's performant and seems to be similar to `sample()`:

```
create table t1 as 
    select level id, cast ('item'||level as varchar2(32)) item 
    from dual connect by level<=100000; 

Table T1 created.

update t1 set item='*'||item 
where exists (
    select rnd from (
        select dbms_random.value() rnd
        from t1
    ) t2 where t2.rowid = t1.rowid and rnd < 0.15
);

14,858 rows updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.717
```

Consider that alias `rnd` must be included in select clause. Otherwise changes the omptimizer the filter predicat from `RND<0.1` to `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE()<0.1`. In that case `dbms_random.value` will be executed only once.

As mentioned in answer @JonHeller, the best solution remains the pl/sql code block because it allows to avoid full table scan. Here is my suggestion:

```
create or replace type rowidListType is table of varchar(18);  
/
create or replace procedure updateRandomly (prefix varchar2 := '*') is
    rowidList rowidListType;  
begin  
    select rowidtochar (rowid) bulk collect into rowidList
    from t1 sample(15)
    ;
    update t1 set item=prefix||item 
    where exists (
        select 1 from table (rowidList) t2
        where chartorowid(t2.column_value) = t1.rowid
    );
    dbms_output.put_line ('updated '||sql%rowcount||' rows.'); 
end;
/
begin  updateRandomly; end;
/ 

Elapsed: 00:00:00.293
updated 14892 rows.
```