# How can one update a table using row number or column number in MySQL or Oracle?

Tags: mysql, oracle

How can one update a table using row number or column number in MySQL or Oracle?

As "`update test set name='Ranjan' where rownum=1;`" this worked in Oracle but not for any other row.
Here is the Table (name=test) for your reference:

---

```
   ID NAME
----- ----------
  101 prabhakar
  102 Dhiraj
  103 Pankaj
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use `ID` in where clause to update?

Comment: I know that but I wanna know if there is any other possibility to do so.

Comment: I'm not clear if you are asking how to update all rows in oracle and mysql or if you want to know the mysql way of only updating the first row.

Comment: Yes there is a possibility. But it is not  what `ROWNUM` is meant for. What your question actually asks for is somewhat like  "I want to update  the second row from my table" - This question actually has no meaning as you are not referring to the data w.r.t a particular column.  It could mean any random row. We are always interested in things like second highest salary, second in alphabetical order etc. Just saying second row from a table means nothing to anyone.

Comment: Hello Salmon,
No, I just want to update any random data using the row number or column number(like 1, 2, 3) if possible in Oracle as well as MySQL. Please see the query mentioned in the question above for your reference.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rownum in Oracle is the rownum of the data within the returned set. If you put a where condition in that query, or you create a query with a join, you will still have a rownum=1 but it won't necessarily be the same returned row. 
ROWID might be more useful for updating, and there's a description here of how to randomly update rows using SQL.

[Update n random rows in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193000/update-n-random-rows-in-sql)

Be sure that this is what you wanted...

Comment: Thanks a lot Percona for your explanation!! 

Comment: You are welcome. Might have to check for the equivalent in MySQL but even though I am Percona I am more familiar with Oracle at the moment (newbie)

Answer (score 0):

Your query will update only one row because there is only one row with rownum=1 :

```
update test set name='Ranjan' where rownum=1;
```

Take a look at [oracle rownum documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm)

Comment: Yeah I have clearly mentioned that the above query worked but not for other rows rather just for 1st row. 

If you could please explain me if there is a way to update via row number or column number in MySQL as well as Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, updating second row / third row etc  is of no worth to anyone as we have no control over display order. And we cannot completely rely on `PSEUDOCOLUMNS` to select a particular row.

An update statement using `ROWNUM` for updating higher values could look like this.

```
UPDATE table1
SET    name = 'Ranjan'
WHERE  id IN (SELECT id
              FROM   (SELECT ROWNUM rn,
                             t.*
                      FROM   table1 t)
              WHERE  rn = 2);
```

Note that here we had to rely on ID column to update the rows as it is like an anchor to fix to a particular row. That is the whole point of having `UNIQUE KEY`s/ `PRIMARY KEY`s etc on particular columns of our tables.You can also notice that `ROWNUM` is  accessed outside the parentheses because `ROWNUM` pseudocolumn returns a number indicating the order in which Oracle selects the row from a table . Thus it is ambiguous to refer to `ROWNUM = 2` inside. As such this `update` is meaningless. However, If I make it `FROM table1 t ORDER BY name` inside parentheses, it means  I am updating the row which has the `ID` of the name that falls second in the alphabetical order. Same might apply for other columns used in order by like `salary` , hire_date etc if applicable.

Please read the documentation and understand clearly the meaning of `ROWNUM` .

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot kaushik for the detailed explanation. 